# Why does xargs cause apt-get to abort?

Tags: apt, xargs

I'm trying to remove a list of packages from a file. I'm using the following command:

```
cat packages | xargs sudo apt-get remove
```

`packages` is my file containing a list of packages I want to remove. Everything appears to work, but `apt-get` aborts instead of letting me choose yes or no.

I know I can get around this with the `-y` option, but I would like to know why this is happening and how can I keep the interactive choice.

Comment: How does it "work well" when it sounds like it doesn't work at all? What does an entry in your file look like? Have you tried `sudo xargs --arg-file packages apt-get remove`?

Comment: Well, it kind of "works" because apt-get gets to the point of removing the right packages. That said, --arg-file was what I was looking for. You can put that in an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

```
xargs -a packages sudo apt-get remove
```

will direct `xargs` to read arguments from `packages`, and so it will leave stdin unmolested.

Answer (score 10):

A more general solution would be

```
 sudo apt-get remove `cat packages`
```

where you will have a problem if the list of [packages is really long](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060).

The reason that it isn't working is that apt-get is trying to read your confirmation from the standard input which - because of the pipe - is attached to `cat`. Contrariwise, `sudo` does the Right Thing by asking your password by opening /dev/tty directly. Apt should do this but apparently doesn't.

Comment: The standard input of xargs is connected to the pipe from `cat`, but the process started by xargs has its standard input coming from /dev/null. This is the behavior of xargs. Simple demonstration: `echo "" | xargs ls -l /dev/self/fd`

Comment: @mws: No, `apt-get` shouldn't open `/dev/tty`. Otherwise you couldn't do things like `yes | apt-get`. Passwords are pretty much the only case where reading from `/dev/tty` is the right thing, and even that much is debatable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, both are correct and better thought than my slap-dash response, which I'm going to leave un-edited so that the comments still make sense.

Comment: I see. Is there any difference between this and xargs -a filename, like ephemient is suggesting?

Comment: Yes, ephimemient's use of the `--arg-file` option is even better for the specific case which is why I upvoted it. For the many commands that don't have such an option the backtick-cat metaphor still has its uses.

Answer (score 2):

Because `apt-get` is removing more than one package, and therefore must confirm the action. Since it's reading `STDIN` from a pipe and is not connected to the terminal it auto assumes `No`.

Another way to get around this is to add `APT::Get::Assume-Yes` to `apt.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently xargs redirects STDIN which confuses apt-get to assume that it is running in non-interactive mode.

I would probably use something like

```
sudo apt-get remove $(cat packages)
```

to avoid using xargs at all.

("--arg-file" is neither in apt-get(8) man nor in my active vocabulary).

Answer (score 1):

To work around.

With GNU xargs and ksh/zsh/bash:

```
sudo xargs -r --arg-file <(cat packages) apt-get remove
```

(of course, if the command is just `cat`, then you can replace `<(cat packages)` with `packages`.

Or:

```
< packages sudo xargs sh -c 'exec apt-get remove "$@" < /dev/tty' sh
```

Depending on the format of the "packages" file (xargs is expecting a blank-separated list of arguments and processes quotes (`"`, `'` and `\`), while `$(...)` doesn't process quotes and expands globbing patterns), you could also do:

```
sudo apt-get remove $(cat packages)
```

But please note that many operating systems have a limit on the length of a command line, so that may not work if the list is big (while `xargs` will work around the issue by running several `apt-get` commands).

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but you can try this and see if it works:

```
yes | sudo apt-get remove $(cat packages)
```